# Solr Suggester - Store Lookup build failed

Tags: solr, solr6

I've exhausted my search efforts as to why this isn't working. I believe I'm following the documentation correctly found at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester

However, every time I attempt to build the suggester, I receive the error "SolrSuggester - Store Lookup build failed." in the logs. I can see it creating the directory for the store correctly on disk, however, there is no data within the file.

I've also tried removing the line `<str name="storeDir">fuzzy_dir</str>`. If I do this and try building, I don't receive the error in the logs, however, I still receive no results.

Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong?

I'm using Solr 6.5.0.

Here is what I have in my schema.xml:

```
<field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="term" type="suggestType" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<copyField source="name" dest="term" />

<fieldType name="suggestType" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Here is what I have in my solrconfig.xml:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">fuzzySuggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="storeDir">fuzzy_dir</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">term</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">suggestType</str>
        <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy" >
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.dictionary">fuzzySuggester</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">5</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

This is how I'm executing the build:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/my_core/suggest?suggest.build=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After endless hours of scouring the internet and attempting suggestions provided by others on this post, I've come to the conclusion something in my solrconfig.xml or schema.xml file was corrupt.

**My fix was to create a completely new core and migrate the pieces I was using in solrconfig.xml and schema.xml to get it to work.** Unfortunately I don't have a better answer, but this is what I had to do in order to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you might be missing this in the fuzzySuggester:

```
<str name="weightField">WEIGHT</str>
```

even if the docs say it's an optional param, I think it might be what is messing with you. If you don't have a good field that you can use, you can just declare one like this:

```
<field name="WEIGHT" type="tfloat" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

and just don't bother putting any data into it.

Comment: I had actually tried that as well previously, but from your suggestion added it back in to give it another shot. Same result when trying to build. "SolrSuggester - Store Lookup build failed"

Comment: I have one suggester running fine with this config mostly, it's just an AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory. You could try changing the lookupImpl param...

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `suggester.dictionary=fuzzySuggester` in the query.

> `http://localhost:8983/solr/my_core/suggest?suggest.build=true&suggester.dictionary=fuzzySuggester`

Comment: This provided the same result error message as I've stated in my question.

Comment: solrconfig looks good, issue can be in schema file. Does name field always present in your index else try required="false"  build the index again and then try building the suggester.